# unable to rate my app

Tags: android, google-play

I am using the below class to `rate` my app. But the every time I do this, it says "Requested item not found". but the link < play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx >   works perfectly in the browser. Why is it not working here?

One more thing I noticed that if I change the package name to the same of some other app, it works. Is there any chance that  something might have been missed while uploading the previous version?

```
public class apprater {
private final static String APP_TITLE = "abcd";
private final static String APP_PNAME = "com.xxx.xxx";

private final static int DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT = 3;
private final static int LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT = 7;

public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
    if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) { return ; }

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    // Increment launch counter
    long launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0) + 1;
    editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

    // Get date of first launch
    Long date_firstLaunch = prefs.getLong("date_firstlaunch", 0);
    if (date_firstLaunch == 0) {
        date_firstLaunch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        editor.putLong("date_firstlaunch", date_firstLaunch);
    }

    // Wait at least n days before opening
    if (launch_count >= LAUNCHES_UNTIL_PROMPT) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= date_firstLaunch + 
                (DAYS_UNTIL_PROMPT * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
            showRateDialog(mContext, editor);
        }
    }

    editor.commit();
}   

public static void showRateDialog(final Context mContext, final SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    dialog.setTitle("Rate " + APP_TITLE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText("If you enjoy using " + APP_TITLE + ", please take a moment to rate it. Thanks for your support!");
    tv.setWidth(240);
    tv.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 10);
    ll.addView(tv);

    Button b1 = new Button(mContext);
    b1.setText("Rate " + APP_TITLE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
            System.out.println("eeeeeeeeeeeee: "+APP_PNAME);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });        
    ll.addView(b1);

    Button b2 = new Button(mContext);
    b2.setText("Remind me later");
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b2);

    Button b3 = new Button(mContext);
    b3.setText("No, thanks");
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editor != null) {
                editor.putBoolean("dontshowagain", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ll.addView(b3);

    dialog.setContentView(ll);        
    dialog.show();        
}
}
```

This what I am using now:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                final String appName = APP_PNAME;

                try 
                {
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xxx.xxx")));


                }
               catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
                {                           
                   mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx")));
                }


               // mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));


                dialog.dismiss();
            }
```

Comment: You're using a `market://` link, if you use `play.google.com/store...` the system will offer to open it with the Google Play app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
final String appName = getPackageName();

    try 
    {
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ appName)));                      
    }
   catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
    {                           
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+ appName)));
    }
```

Comment: sometimes it will tack time to affect in mobile device. I faced same issue when I removed one app from my developer account and try to see in browser it said no item found but when I opened in play store using link in mobile then it was seen and also able to download. So I think its tacking more time to affect in mobile play store than browser.

Comment: But the thing is that I have my app already in the market with the package name `com.xxx.xxx` and I want to add the rating feature in the newer version that I am planning to release.

Comment: ohh I see .. Are you using `getPackageName()` ? because some times silly mistake for name is also there and we can't get it...

Comment: Please see I have update the code. I am not using `getPackagename` now. But the problem still exists.

Comment: :One more thing I noticed that if I change the package name to the same of some other app, it works. Is there any chance that  something might have been missed while uploading the previous version?

Comment: I am suggesting you to use `getPackagename` instead of manually use text for package name.  `if I change the package name to the same of some other app, it works.` For this : there must be package name difference. Use Log and copy that link to web browser and  test there.